# Connecting to Linux Prompt with Telnet

Tags: linux, arduino

I have an Arduino and Ethernet Shield coded to create a simple serial to telnet client. This works fine for connecting serial terminal programs to Telnet BBS type systems such as the one at bbs.thebytexchange.com using port 23.

When I use the same client to communicate with my Arch box it connects OK, however, I immediately receive 5 bytes from the Arch box, and everything stops. No matter what I send to the Arch box nothing is returned.
The five bytes (in hex) as as follows. 18 20 23 27 24. If I connect to a Raspberry Pi running Raspian I get four bytes returned (18 20 23 27) with the same symptoms.

I am happy that each of the Telnet servers are running fine as I can connect and log on to both boxes using Telnet from my Mac using the standard Telnet app and I can Telnet to localhost on each machine also. I am happy that the serial to Telnet Arduino is fine as I can Telnet using a serial terminal (any) to internet Telnet resources, however, I am clearly missing something when connecting to a Linux logon prompt, any ideas what that might be?

Kind Regards

John

UPDATE: Further investigation indicates that what I am seeing is an attempt from the server to get me to negotiate a few options. The bytes I am seeing are each preceded with FF (didn't notice this initially due to FF being filtered out from the monitoring). The bytes are part of the Telnet protocol and mean the following:

- FF FD 18 logout
- FF FD 20 data Entry terminal
- FF FD 27 output marking
- FF FD 24 terminal type

The question now becomes, how do I respond to this?

Comment: You can have more information about the error by turning ON the socket level debugging of the telnet binary. Use `telnet -d <host> <port>` or in the telnet session type `toggle debug` to enable and disable debugging.

Comment: As mentioned in the question there is no error when telnet <ip> <port> is used. And my homemade Telnet client works fine when connecting to Telnet BBSs, however, when connecting to a Linux login I get the responses as mentioned. I am thinking that this is some sort of application protocol I am not handling.

Comment: From a quick search, it seems you can respond to any of the server's requests with a `WONT` reply, i.e. server: `0xFF xx` -> you: `0xFF 0xFC xx`. See e.g.  [here](http://mud-dev.wikidot.com/telnet:negotiation).

Comment: Are there any other bytes filtered away? I think there should be a third byte in each of the messages from the server, pattern `IAC,<type of operation>,<option>` with the `<type of operation>` implying which kind of response you need to send (`DONT` vs. `WONT`). Another source: http://pcmicro.com/netfoss/telnet.html

Comment: My bad, a typo at my end... the sequences are all DO sequences with three bytes . I have updated the Question with the correct received byte sequences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of [JimmyB](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1015327/jimmyb), I discovered the approach needed so will answer my own question.

As mentioned previously the received sequences from the Telnet server are attempts by the server to negotiate some options for the connection. These options are aimed at enhancing the default configuration of a Network Virtual Terminal (NVT) at each end. These option requests simply need to be acknowledged as suggested by [JimmyB](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1015327/jimmyb).

The process is defined in [RFC854](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc854) which makes clear that I should respond to DO requests with either WILL or WONT and WILL requests with either DO or DONT.

In my case I do not need these enhancements as I am happy with a default NVT for the connection. Therefore, in order to get to the Linux Login prompt I respond to each DO request with a WONT, for example;

When receiving the following DO request (FD indicates a DO for option 18)

```
FF FD 18
```

I respond with a WONT response (indicated by FC)

```
FF FC 18
```

Similarly if I had received a WILL request (FB)

```
FF FB 18
```

I would return a DONT (FE)

```
FF FE 18
```

I hope this helps.